# how to group data by positive or negative number in pandas

Tags: python

my data set:

```
*195    -1.888996
196    -4.402077*
197     0.171813
198     2.182845
199     2.349494
200     2.239476
*201    -0.340724
202    -3.056798
203    -4.815240
204    -8.040102
205    -9.316368
206    -9.410789
207    -7.844607
208    -4.791272
209    -4.273477
210    -1.660889
211    -0.931744
212    -1.163933
213    -0.452218*
214     1.580649
215     4.331421
216     6.101737
```

I want to group data like that negative group and positive group alternatively. I tried below.

```
df['flag']=df.MACD.apply(lambda x:True if x>0 else False)
df.MACD.groupby(df.flag).sum()

flag
False   -738.959009
True     873.042392
Name: MACD, dtype: float64
```

Only got two groups. But I want to negative group and then positive group and then negative group ... and also every group is independent.

Comment: What's the desired output of your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do a groupby on a particular column, pandas makes groups of unique values of a that group ; here in your case there are only two groups based on flags, the True group and False group. When you apply sum on groupby object you get sum on each group. 
one good way to check after grouping is to check using a for loop, for example say

```
gpd=df.MACD.groupby(df.flag)
for label,grp in gpd:
    print(grp)
```

from your question it looks like you want sum of consecutive positives and negative segments, here is one way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=[-1,-2,1,1,-2,-2,2,3,1]
df['positives']=df.where(df['a']>0).apply(np.cumsum)
df['negatives']=df.where(df['a']<0).apply(np.cumsum)
```

should result in

```
    a   positives   negatives
0   -1  NaN         -1.0
1   -2  NaN         -3.0
2   1   1.0         NaN
3   1   2.0         NaN
4   -2  NaN         -5.0 
5   -2  NaN         -7.0
6   2   4.0         NaN
7   3   7.0         NaN
8   1   8.0         NaN
```

so your required positive values are in index 3,8 and negatives in index 1,5
if you also want to remove those consecutive elements and just report these locations automatically then consider using something like df.shift

```
df['flag']=df.a.apply(lambda x:True if x>0 else False) #adds a flags like your example.
df['compare']=df['flag']==df['flag'].shift(-1)
df[df['compare']==False]
```

should result in

```
    a   positives   negatives   flag    compare
1   -2  NaN         -3.0       False    False
3   1   2.0         NaN        True     False
5   -2  NaN         -7.0       False    False
8   1   8.0         NaN        True     False
```

positives and negatives are consecutive sums of consecutive positive and negative segments.

UPDATE: update to solution (comment from OP)
what is needed is aggregarion of independent positives and negative segments.
one way is to define a simple function like below

```
def signed_agg(pd_col):
    val=0
    sgn=None
    col_iter=pd_col.iteritems()
    try:
        while True:
            x=col_iter.next()[1]
            if not sgn:
                sgn=np.sign(x)
            if not np.sign(x)==sgn:
                yield val
                val=x
                sgn=np.sign(x)
            else:
                val+=x
                tmp,sgn=(sgn,np.nan)
                yield sgn
                sgn=tmp
    except StopIteration: 
        yield val
```

passing a column to this function and making a dataframe that can be merged with original

```
pd.DataFrame(signed_agg(df['a']),columns=['signed_agg'])
```

yields

```
    signed_agg
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   -3.0
3   NaN
4   2.0
5   NaN
6   -4.0
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   6.0
```

one could also write a function in similar way that can be used by apply method but then instead of try , except block ,we need to use a if statement checking if the element is last value of the column.

Comment: Suvy,thank you for so detail answer. Sorry for my not good original description. My actual objective is that, every segment is independent, for your 'a' example: first segment -3, second segment 2, third segment -4, four segment 6.

Comment: edited the solution, may be you could also edit the question a bit so that it is clearer for others?